# Is MQ Light truely a message queue?

Tags: message-queue, ibm-cloud

We are running a Node.JS app on Bluemix that uses the mqlight service.

Are the messages really being queued in case there are no receivers? Is it possible for a receiver to fetch messages that were sent before it connected?

Are messages really being queued in case messages are being sent faster than they are handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the *Time-To-Live* property of messages, messages can be persisted on the destination topic until a subscriber connects. This will allow you to buffer messages whilst they are no subscribers.

Full details for this property are available [here](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/mq-light/docs/time-to-live/).